# How to stop 508 Jaws aria alert queue

Tags: javascript, jaws-screen-reader, aria-live

My current codebase uses the following function to create alerts to notify blind users that that something has occurred, e.g. "Bob successfully assigned to Blue team."

```
var create508Message = function (message, type) {
    var $messageElement,
        templateOptions = {
            message: message
        };

    // create the $messageElement
    switch (type){
        case 'alert':
            templateOptions.isAlert = true;
            $messageElement = $(HBS['common/accessibilityUtil'](templateOptions));
            break;
        case 'status':
            templateOptions.isStatus = true;
            $messageElement = $(HBS['common/accessibilityUtil'](templateOptions));
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    // trigger the message
    $('body').append($messageElement);
    // clean up automatically after 5 secs
    setTimeout(function (){
        $messageElement.remove();
    }, 5000);

},
```

Most reusable components will let a blind user know the current state. I am running into some problems, where for instance, a table when is refreshed, the number of pages are read, and then a filter is applied, and the page number changes, because the number of items in the filtered list has changed. 
This leads to Jaws reading to a blind user a number of conflicting states, because it reads the entire queue of alerts.

I was hoping there was a way to prevent it from reading the queue, something like:

```
killAriaLive: function () {
    $('div[aria-live]').map( function () {
            $(this).removeAttr('aria-live');
            $(this).removeAttr('role');
            $(this).attr('hidden', 'true');
            $(this).attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
    });
},
```

but that didn't work either, it still reads the entire queue of messages.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create/update an element with aria-live="assertive" (see https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/03/screen-reader-support-aria-live-regions/) with spaces (I haven't tried this yet though) however, you could then start suppressing speech that the user legitimately needs to hear.